# Commit to GIT with UTF-8 With BOM

Tags: git, powershell, visual-studio-code

As the subject suggests, how would I go about committing changes to Git using the UTF-8 with BOM encoding, and then ensure VS Code keeps this encoding format throughout the dev cycle?

My scripts keep getting encoded incorrectly and running with additional characters but need to make sure this is changed on all interfaces.

Comment: Most languages which use UTF-8 for encoding don't use a BOM.  For example, anything with a shebang will be broken if you use a BOM.  If you just want to use UTF-8 without the BOM, that's easier.

Comment: I had issues too with PowerShell script and BOM, but for gitlab i just found the solution to avoid every HTTP upload/commit/changes. Using git.exe with a commit/push uploading a UTF8-BOM file does not change the encoding. If it does, then you might have settings on your target repository that enforces utf8 for example - so that might remove the BOM. Details on documented errors: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22155#note_507789673

Comment: @CallumStones: for context, can you please explain what kind of files you are storing in your repository ? (C# files ? powershell scripts ? ...)

Comment: I'm also looking for the encoding name we should indicate to gitattributes to store files with UTF-8 with BOM encoding... Concerned files are .iss for innosetup (since version 6à) that requires a BOM to work correctly.